# time complexity when while not execute

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

What is the “best case” time complexity of the following segment of program?

```
n=0
sum=0
input(x)
while x!=-999 do
  n=n+1
  sum=sum+x
  input(x)
end {while}
mean=sum/n
```

Does "best case" could be O(1) when user in the first time type “-999” 
note: when user type -999 in first time, "mean" will be 0/0, result of function is undefined

Comment: This isn't Java and it sounds rather like homework?

Comment: To talk about O(N), you need to define N...

Answer (score 0):

The worst case is infinity,which means this program never stops. I would not even call it an algorithm, as some definitions of "algorithm" require a finite set of inputs, while other require that it terminates before a given number of calculation steps.

Which means `O()` is not applicable here.

Comment: you told: "The worst case is infinity,which means this program never stops". So what about best case if user type in the first time -999?

Answer (score -1):

Algorithm's complexity is usually defined in relation to some kind of data. It can be the input data, as in your case.

Imagine for a while, that the data is not inputted manually, but provided in an array in the app. What would the complexity be then?

In this case the amount of numbers processed is N, and the loop runs once for each N, so you can assume that the complexity is O(N).

Comment: *IF* complexity term can be used with this problem, then the complexity is O(N) regardless of the data! If N==0 then O(N)=O(0)=0, but it's still O(N). Worst case/best case can be applied if there are some conditions in the algorithm - in this case there are none, there's only the amount of data.